# "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table employee(  Employee_ID int primary key,   Name nvarchar(20),
     Gender nvarchar(2),   DOJ datetime,  Manager nvarchar(20),
     Department nvarchar(20),
     Tenure  as (SELECT DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(),DOJ ) )     )
```

Error :

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Comment: Simply skip the SELECT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `SELECT` statement for computed column just do :

```
create table employee (
     Employee_ID int primary key,   Name nvarchar(20),
     Gender nvarchar(2), DOJ datetime,  Manager nvarchar(20),
     Department nvarchar(20)
     Tenure as (datediff(year, getdate(), DOJ))
 )
```

Comment: //[Route(StaticClass1.employee)]
        //[HttpGet]
        //public IQueryable<Employee> getallemployee()
        //{
        //    return db.Employees
        //        .ToList()
        //        .Select(p => new Employee
        //        {
        //            Employee_ID = p.Employee_ID,
        //            Name = p.Name,
        //         Manager = p.Manager,
        //           Department = p.Department
        //        })
        //        .AsQueryable();
        //}

Comment: showing the rest of the field with the null values but we want only some selected field without showing other fields